# ListView custom background colors

Tags: android, listview

I need to have even rows as white and odd rows sd grey in my `ListView` (using `ArrayAdapter` to populate it). I can't use different `layouts` with different `background` color because if I do the selection doesn't work. What I do is just use this piece of code in my `getView()` to check if row is odd or even and apply background depending on condition:

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_item_background));}
```

But this doesn't work as expected because the only first visible rows are of correct background color. After scrolling to the bottom (I assume because of recycling mechanism) I have very weird behavior and don't understand why. Here is what I have for the first items (correct case):

[image]

Here is what I have after scrolling:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a longer snippet of the code?

Comment: Well, the other people already answered. But yeah, you need an else statement for the light ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `getView()` objects are reused for better performance.Thats why you get this weird behavior. To solve your problem just add if - else

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
   convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_item_background));
} else {
   convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_item_background));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set default color for any reused convert view first, because convert view already can have dark background. So it would be something like this:

```
convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_item_background));
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_item_background));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ELSE cause as well otherwise all the backgrounds will become black because of the reusing mechanism.

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
   convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_item_background));
} else {
   convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_item_background));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the background of the listview rows as below:

> ```
> if (position % 2 == 0) {
> ```
>
> convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_item_background));
>   }
>   else
>   {
>   convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_item_background));
>   }